# Equation rearranging in Java

Tags: java, equation, solver

Is there any java library that can rearrange equations as the following:

```
Input equation: x = y * 2
What I need from lib: Rearrange so that y becomes subject
Output string: y = x / 2
```

I've searched a lot,but most libraries I found can only solve equations (by finding values that satisfy equations) but are not capable of rearrangements.

Thanks

Comment: In such simple examples regex could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is symbolic algebra:

http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/

Your example is a *very* simple one.  More complex equations will be more challenging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is just an example to what I need. The library of course needs to handle more complicated formulas

Comment: Simple algebra is one thing.  Add in transcendental functions, exponentials, logarithms, calculus - how complex do you need to go?

Comment: I have read the documentation of the tool you posted as well as few other tools (mostly in .NET). However, non of them seem to have an API for what I need. Regarding your question, I need this for an experiment I'm conducting, so algebra should be fine (for now).